# slow down object rotation Unity

Tags: c#

This is my code for an object rotating by the mouse but I want to slow it down to about 18° a second. 
This is  about a 2d top down tank game.

```
private Vector3 mouse_pos;
public Transform target;
private Vector3 object_pos;
private float angle;

private void Start()
{
   

}

void Update()
{
    mouse_pos = Input.mousePosition;
    mouse_pos.z = -20;
    object_pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position);
    mouse_pos.x = mouse_pos.x - object_pos.x;
    mouse_pos.y = mouse_pos.y - object_pos.y;
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(mouse_pos.y, mouse_pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle - 90);
    
}
```

Comment: reduce the angle in your rotation. Try to find a factor that suits you. You can use DeltaTime to make proper calculation and ensure a fixed angle/sec ratio.